# Openlayers point not in same location over WMS map and WMTS map

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, map-projections

I've been trying to get openlayers 3 working with two different Tiles, WMTS and WMS with a point at (69.69, 18.95) which is a coordinate in Tromsø, Norway. The tiles for the maps are using a projection of EPSG:32633 and therefore I found out that i had to include proj4, cause OL3 does not support that projection (?). Anyways, here are the jsfiddle of it. The first link:
https://jsfiddle.net/larsimann8/xo8nk8qL/4/: `.` is with the WMS which actually the point is at the right place, but with the second link which is with WMTS: https://jsfiddle.net/larsimann8/6y566j31/ `.` its not.

I can't really see what is wrong here, so if anyone knows please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddles are not working properly, I can't see anything at the moment.

However, the problem is related with the ol.tilegrid.WMTS params.

You are setting the origin at -20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244 , while the WMTS origin for EPSG:32633 is -2500000.0 9045984.0

Check the capabilities document to configure the layer correctly.

Comment: Can i ask where you got those numbers from?

Comment: From the capabilities document of the WMTS service you are using: https://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_wmts?request=getcapabilities

Comment: Thanks. What about the resolution? How is this calculated what the start resolution should be before dividing it down. The map has in the document of the WMTS service a width of 256 and a height of 256.

Comment: I see this number in <ScaleDenominator>7.737142857142858E7</ScaleDenominator> which is devided by the factor of 2 for every matrix id, but when i try to do the same it is not even on the map anymore.